# Chat functionality with jQuery & PHP not writing to database

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, ajax

I'm trying to create the start of a chat page with jQuery and PHP. However, when I have set up a simple page to write to my database, the echo statement of **Added** appears, but it does not add to my database.

I have created one php web page **chat** including the jQuery statement and HTML textboxes. Each ID corresponds to the statement.
The second php page **addChat.php** contains the PHP and SQL statement to write to my database.

It's not showing any errors, but it will not add to my database. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $.post("addChat.php",{name: $("#name").val(), msg: $("msg").val()},function(data,status){
            alert(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli("localhost:3308","root","","fypdatabase");
$st=$con->prepare("insert into chat(name,message) values(?,?)");
$st->bind_param("ss", $_POST["name"],$_POST["msg"]);
$st->execute();
echo "Added";
```

Comment: check for [mysqli::error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) and the return of `execute()` to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Try to use socket.io instead of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to give port give it as last paramteter

```
 $con = new con('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'fypdatabase', 3308);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", con_connect_error());
    echo "error";
    exit();
}


$st=$con->prepare("INSERT INTO chat(name,message) values(?,?)");
$st->bind_param("ss", $_POST["name"],$_POST["msg"]);

/* execute prepared statement */
$st->execute();

echo "Added";

/* close statement and connection */
$st->close();

/* close connection */
$con->close();
```

Comment: `con_connect_errno()`? Wouldn't it rather be `$con->connect_errno`?

Comment: @digijay yes we can check like this also if($con->connect_error)

Comment: @Darán if my answer help you please upvote / accept my answer